# How do I fix graphical issues with compiz and gnome-shell?

Tags: drivers, gnome, graphics, compiz, desktop-environments

I installed compiz in Ubuntu 18.04 and have some graphical problems,   such as lags when moving windows and watching movies.

In compiz, it's ok, but not in gnome-shell.

I tried to reinstall xorg-server, but that didn't work.

My first language is not English so please forgive me for my mistakes :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'compiz' session, so what are you using, unity or something else that uses compiz? Was a gnome session (gnome-shell) ok before installing compiz & whatever or was it always bad?

Comment: no before that was good, i installed unity and work great but gnome :(